# Using ExcelDataReader to read Excel data starting from a particular cell

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

I am using [`ExcelDataReader`](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to read data from my Excel workbook in C#.
But structure of my Excel sheet is such that data to be read can start from any particular cell and not necessarily `A1`.

Can any one Please suggest a way on how this can be achieved using `ExcelDataReader`?

Answer (score 81):

If you are using `ExcelDataReader 3+` you will find that there isn't any method for `AsDataSet()` for your reader object, You need to also install another package for [`ExcelDataReader.DataSet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader.DataSet/), then you can use the `AsDataSet()` method.
Also there is not a property for `IsFirstRowAsColumnNames` instead you need to set it inside of `ExcelDataSetConfiguration`.

Example:

```
using (var stream = File.Open(originalFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    IExcelDataReader reader;

    // Create Reader - old until 3.4+
    ////var file = new FileInfo(originalFileName);
    ////if (file.Extension.Equals(".xls"))
    ////    reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
    ////else if (file.Extension.Equals(".xlsx"))
    ////    reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    ////else
    ////    throw new Exception("Invalid FileName");
    // Or in 3.4+ you can only call this:
    reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)

    //// reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames
    var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true 
        }
    };

    var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf);

    // Now you can get data from each sheet by its index or its "name"
    var dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

    //...
}
```

---

You can find row number and column number of a cell reference like this:

```
var cellStr = "AB2"; // var cellStr = "A1";
var match = Regex.Match(cellStr, @"(?<col>[A-Z]+)(?<row>\d+)");
var colStr = match.Groups["col"].ToString();
var col = colStr.Select((t, i) => (colStr[i] - 64) * Math.Pow(26, colStr.Length - i - 1)).Sum();
var row = int.Parse(match.Groups["row"].ToString());
```

Now you can use some loops to read data from that cell like this:

```
for (var i = row; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = col; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        var data = dataTable.Rows[i][j];
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

You can filter rows and columns of your Excel sheet at read time with this config:

```
var i = 0;
var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
{
    UseColumnDataType = true,
    ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
    {
        FilterRow = rowReader => fromRow <= ++i - 1,
        FilterColumn = (rowReader, colIndex) => fromCol <= colIndex,
        UseHeaderRow = true
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that in new version (v3.4) is not necessary validate file extension, because of ExcelDataReader validate for us. In case file Extension is invalid, it will generate a exception. [Reference](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#how-to-use)

Comment: @LuisEduardox tnx, I update my answer to show your comment ;).

Comment: thanks so much for this great function. i have a date in XLSX format 10/08/2018 for some reason when i convert this to CSV format, it's inserting a time as well 10/08/2018 12:00:00AM i've attempted attacking this by setting UseColumnDataType = false however, that yielded the same result

Comment: Would love an example

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I found your question and add an example as an answer, HTH ;).

Comment: In the above code - just in case you were wondering -  the Sheets in a Workbook have index starting at zero - so:    var dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0]  references Sheet 1 in a workbook and   var dataTable = dataSet.Tables[1]  references Sheet2 in a Workbook etc etc ...

Comment: @GrantShannon tnx, and I add a comment to code to notify that -HTH ;).

Comment: what is the underscore named? _ =>

Comment: @toha in C# when we need to pass a variable to an arrow function (lamda) and we know that we will never use it in that function, we usually use underscore as a variable name [An old naming convention] -HTH ;)

Comment: @shA.t Correct. It is variable name which is will be send to arrow function.. Writer does not care what is name of variable. so he put underscore instead of x or anything else name of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300654/underscore-arrow-what-is-this

Answer (score 36):

To be more clear, I will begin at the beginning.

I will rely on the sample code found in https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader, but with some modifications to avoid inconveniences.

The following code detects the file format, either xls or xlsx.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader;

//1. Reading Excel file
if (Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
{
    //1.1 Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
    excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
}
else
{
    //1.2 Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
    excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
}

//2. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

//3. DataSet - Create column names from first row
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = false;
```

Now we can access the file contents in a more convenient way. I use DataTable for this. The following is an example to access a specific cell, and print its value in the console:

```
DataTable dt = result.Tables[0];
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[rowPosition][columnPosition]);
```

If you do not want to do a DataTable, you can do the same as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(result.Tables[0].Rows[rowPosition][columnPosition]);
```

It is important not try to read beyond the limits of the table, for this you can see the number of rows and columns as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(result.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
Console.WriteLine(result.Tables[0].Columns.Count);
```

Finally, when you're done, you should close the reader and free resources:

```
//5. Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
excelReader.Close();
```

I hope you find it useful.

(I understand that the question is old, but I make this contribution to enhance the knowledge base, because there is little material about particular implementations of this library).

Comment: is it possible to do this on `HttpRequest` body rather than a filestream? i have a payload that's coming in via the body of a POST request

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' It's been a long time since I used the library, but I read the documentation now, and apparently it only supports FileStream. One idea that occurs to me, is to use GetResponseStream() and store your payload in a file, then perform the classic procedure.

Answer (score 10):

**For ExcelDataReader v3.6.0 and above.**
I struggled a bit to iterate over the Rows. So here's a little more to the above code. Hope it helps for few atleast.

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(copyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {

                        IExcelDataReader excelDataReader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);

                        var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                        {
                            ConfigureDataTable = a => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
                            {
                                UseHeaderRow = true
                            }
                        };

                        DataSet dataSet = excelDataReader.AsDataSet(conf);
                        //DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Sheet1"];
                        DataRowCollection row = dataSet.Tables["Sheet1"].Rows;
                        //DataColumnCollection col = dataSet.Tables["Sheet1"].Columns;

                        List<object> rowDataList = null;
                        List<object> allRowsList = new List<object>();
                        foreach (DataRow item in row)
                        {
                            rowDataList = item.ItemArray.ToList(); //list of each rows
                            allRowsList.Add(rowDataList); //adding the above list of each row to another list
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it :

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(@"c:\working\test.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

The `result.Tables` contains the sheets and the `result.tables[0].Rows` contains the cell rows.

Comment: How exactly would you read an excel starting from a specific cell? Could you please explain little more in detail @Sievajet?

Answer (score 6):

I found this useful to read from a specific column and row:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Desktop\ExcelDataReader.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;         
DataTable dt = result.Tables[0];
string text = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Very easy with ExcelReaderFactory 3.1 and up:

```
using (var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", ValidateNames = true })
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var fs = File.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
        var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
            {
                UseHeaderRow = true // Use first row is ColumnName here :D
            }
        });
        if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            var dtData = dataSet.Tables[0];
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static DataTable ConvertExcelToDataTable(string filePath, bool isXlsx = false)
{
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    //open file and returns as Stream
        using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {

                    var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
                    {
                        ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
                        {
                            UseHeaderRow = true
                        }
                    };

                    var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf);

                    // Now you can get data from each sheet by its index or its "name"
                    var dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

                    Console.WriteLine("Total no of rows  " + dataTable.Rows.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Total no of Columns  " + dataTable.Columns.Count);

                    return dataTable;

                }

        }
   
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is correct or not, but since this is a new answer to a pretty old question with other highly voted answers, it would be useful to summarize what is different about your approach and why you wanted to share it.