# Can't read XLS files when i download them and try to open them in openfiledialog C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015, exceldatareader

So I am downloading some excel files from a service that calculates a day of a worker in this company when I download [this file this comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYnJU.png):
[image: file]

Now I think everything alright, it should work fine.
So here's the deal if I try and open this file in my Visual Studio 2015 with an openfiledialog [I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y99ne.png)

[image: error]

Now when I go and save the excel as 97-2003 xls file it works with `createbinaryreader`. And if I save it as a normal excel format xlsx file it works with `createopenxmlreader`.

How can I fix this so I don't need to go to the excel file and specially save it as a excel-workmap (xls or xlsx)?

PS: I am putting this excel file into a datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

These notes were too mush to comment, so I let them as an answer here:

> Note 1: Use ExcelReaderFactory in aproper way like this:

```
IExcelDataReader reader;
if (file.Extension.Equals(".xls"))
    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
else if (file.Extension.Equals(".xlsx"))
    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
else
    throw new Exception("Invalid Excel File");
```

> Note 2: Use `AsDataSet()` method without parameter.

```
result = reader.AsDataSet();
```

> Note 3: You can use newer version of [`ExcelDataReader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022604/4519059).