# How to add the dependencies of ExcelDataReader and Excel dataset in Azure functions using C#

Tags: c#, excel, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to add the reference for `ExcelDataReader` and `ExcelDataset` in Azure functions? I uploaded dll file of NuGet packages (`exceldatareader.3.4.0.nupkg`) to the program. But I'm not sure how actually it has to be used. Can anyone help me to achieve this.

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
#r "System.IO"
#r "System.Data"
#r "exceldatareader" //*I'm not able to add this reference|*
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using ExcelDataReader;
using System.Data;
```

Thank you.

Comment: what the error or difficulty you faced, what are you tried

Comment: please see the whole process - http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3489/read-a-excel-blob-file-using-excel-data-reader-in-azure

Comment: I have added the reference I tried to add in the question above

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634477/using-exceldatareader-to-read-excel-data-starting-from-a-particular-cell

Comment: @ajay2707 That article is regarding console application right. I'm able to complete my task in the console application. I want to implement the same using the Azure functions. using ExcelDataReader; throws error saying, 'reference is missing'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install packages for Azure functions on portal, we need to create dependencies file under function folder. Click `View files` on the right of function panel, `Add` file according to runtime.

If your function runtime is ~1, create `project.json` with following content.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "ExcelDataReader.DataSet": "3.4.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

If your function runtime is ~2, create `function.proj` as below.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="ExcelDataReader.DataSet" Version="3.4.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After file created, assemblies will be added to function host environment. Also need to remove unnecessary `#r "exceldatareader"` or you will got error.

Comment: I have already found the solution. Thank you for your time and help.