# ExcelDataReader for Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, visual-studio, exceldatareader

I'm trying to read the values from an excel file's stream, unfortunately, after installing `ExcelDataReader` and `ExcelDataReader.DataSet` from NuGet packages, I can't create the class `IExcelDataReader`. It doesn't read the Import neither.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports ExcelDataReader
Public Class ExcelMng
    Public Function Values_GET(stream As Stream)
        Dim reader As IExcelDataReader
    End Function
End Class
```

[Project's Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rTuN.png)

**Error found:**

> 'IExcelDataReader' it's not defined.

**Things I have tried:**

- Uninstall the packages and installing them again.
- Changing versions of the packages installed (I lower them down to 3.3).
- Following tutorials online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQ1PpcIcHno.
- Restarting the project.

**Relevant information:**

- **Platform:** .NET Framework 3.5.
- **Things left to do:** Uninstall dll packages (I'm not really sure what that means).

Comment: You have to use `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader()` or `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader()`, depending on the Excel file version. `ExcelReaderFactory.Create...()` returns a configured Reader. To create a Reader, pass a Stream object and a New `ExcelReaderConfiguration()` object. Don't use the Interface directly. -- Install the NuGet Packages with the Visual Studio `NuGet Package Manager` (see whether the NuGet version you have supports version `3.3.0` of the package)

Comment: Get this Package, too: [ExcelNumberFormat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelNumberFormat)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634477/using-exceldatareader-to-read-excel-data-starting-from-a-particular-cell/46022604

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to run the code, it works well.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim reader As IExcelDataReader
        Dim stream = File.Open("D:\test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
        Dim conf = New ExcelDataSetConfiguration With {
            .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration With {
                .UseHeaderRow = True
            }
        }
        Dim dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf)
        Dim dataTable = dataSet.Tables(0)
    End Sub
```

I noted that we need to install .Net Framework 4.5 to run this program.

[image]