# How to read only columns from Excel using ExcelDataReader?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, datatable, exceldatareader

I am using below code to read column names from Excel sheet. It's working fine. But it loads entire sheet data into datatable. It takes a lot of time. Is there any way we can read only column names and not load whole sheet?

```
   using (var stream = File.Open(strDoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   { 

        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            dt = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
                ConfigureDataTable = (tablereader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true }
            }).Tables["Data"];
        }
    }

    foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
    {
        columnNamesList.Add(col.ToString().Trim());
    }
```

'Data' is the sheet name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest is to read the first row without the overhead of `AsDataSet`:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
    columnNamesList.Add(reader.GetString(i));
}
```

Comment: How to use this code to read particular sheet in the excel? I am reading sheet named 'Data'.

Comment: @SAT The reader object has `Name` property and `NextResult()` method to navigate sheets. Could do something like: `while (reader.Name != "Data" || reader.NextResult()) {}` (untested!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FilterRow` to skip rows. For example:

```
dt = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
{
     ConfigureDataTable = (tablereader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true, FilterRow = rowReader => rowReader.Depth < 1 }
}).Tables["Data"];
```

At this point `dt.Rows.Count` will be 0.

Not sure if this will speed up the response, but it prevents rows from the sheet from being inserted into the DataTable.

Helpful links:

[Using ExcelDataReader to read Excel data starting from a particular cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022604/18789859).

[How skip rows and cells to create the dataset?](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/300#issuecomment-351706295).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this doesn't improve speed.