# what does _ mean regarding ES6 lambda

Tags: javascript, lambda, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am reading some ES6 code with lambda and promisejs

```
 .then(_ => current.quit())
```

I am wondering _ mean in the lambda expression. I tried to change it to (), it also work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300654/underscore-arrow-what-is-this

Comment: It's a parameter name. Nothing special. `function foo(_) { ... }` or `function foo(bar) { ... }`

Comment: `_` means the same thing in ES6 as it has always meant since the beginning. Remember, we even have several libraries that use `_` the same way jQuery use `$` (lodash, underscore). It's just a variable name. You can replace it with `tmp` or `x` or `foo`