# What is the return _ in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question on something I've never seen before in C#. In the service provider in the new asp.net dependency injection, there is a method with `return _ => null;`

https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs
Lines 63-72.

The method in question:

```
private Func<MyServiceProvider, object> CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
{
    var callSite = GetServiceCallSite(serviceType, new HashSet<Type>());
    if (callSite != null)
    {
        return RealizeService(_table, serviceType, callSite);
    }
    return _ => null;
}
```

What is the `_` ? Is it new in C# 6? Searching around for `return _` doesn't return anything useful, unless you want naming conventions.

Comment: It's the name of the argument to your Func

Comment: Same as `return delegate (int _) { return null; };` where `_` is a parameter which is not used (so no need to give a proper name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not using the parameter in a lambda, people use `_` as a convention for indicating that.

In your code, it is the catchall case for if `serviceType` isn't resolved to a call site.  Since you don't care about the `serviceType` to return null, `_` is used for that parameter.

This is probably a duplicate of this post which has lots of info:

[C# style: Lambdas, _ => or x =>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538924/c-sharp-style-lambdas-or-x)

Comment: Thanks for the link with more details. It makes sense now, just a variable name. I was thinking it had some special meaning because that's the first time I've seen an underscore used by itself like that.

Answer (score 2):

_ is a valid C# identifier, so `_ => null` is the same as `myServiceProvider => null`

Defining what is a valid identifier is not as simple as checking the characters for a white list of allowed characters, but it's documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For C#7 onwards, the language (or rather the compiler) recognizes the convention that a single `_` denotes an unimportant value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards

> Starting with C# 7.0, C# supports discards, which are temporary, dummy variables that are intentionally unused in application code. Discards are equivalent to unassigned variables; they do not have a value. Because there is only a single discard variable, and that variable may not even be allocated storage, discards can reduce memory allocations. Because they make the intent of your code clear, they enhance its readability and maintainability.
>
> You indicate that a variable is a discard by assigning it the underscore (_) as its name.