# Using _ (underscore) variable with arrow functions in ES6/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I came across this construct in an Angular example and I wonder why this is chosen:

```
_ => console.log('Not using any parameters');
```

I understand that the variable `_` means don't care/not used but since it is the only variable is there any reason to prefer the use of `_` over:

```
() => console.log('Not using any parameters');
```

Surely this can't be about one character less to type. The `()` syntax conveys the intent better in my opinion and is also more type specific because otherwise I think the first example should have looked like this:

```
(_: any) => console.log('Not using any parameters');
```

In case it matters, this was the context where it was used:

```
submit(query: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['search'], { queryParams: { query: query } })
      .then(_ => this.search());
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300654/underscore-arrow-what-is-this

Comment: How can you be worrying about typing or type specificity for a parameter which is never used?

Comment: I'm a C++ developer by trade so I guess I'm always worried about type specificity :-).

Comment: Personally, the _=> pattern reduces the number of brackets making it easier to read: doStuff().then(()=>action()) vs doStuff().then(_=>action()).

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The reason why this style can be used (and possibly why it was used here) is that `_` is one character shorter than `()`.

Optional parentheses fall into the same style issue as [optional curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-curly-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript). This is a matter of taste and code style for the most part, but verbosity is favoured here because of consistency.

While arrow functions allow a single parameter without parentheses, it is inconsistent with zero, single destructured, single rest and multiple parameters:

```
let zeroParamFn = () => { ... };
let oneParamFn = param1 => { ... };
let oneParamDestructuredArrFn = ([param1]) => { ... };
let oneParamDestructuredObjFn = ({ param1 }) => { ... };
let twoParamsFn = (param1, param2) => { ... };
let restParamsFn = (...params) => { ... };
```

Although `is declared but never used` error [was fixed in TypeScript 2.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#flag-unused-declarations-with---nounusedparameters-and---nounusedlocals) for underscored parameters, `_` can also trigger `unused variable/parameter` warning from a linter or IDE. This is a considerable argument against doing this.

`_` can be conventionally used for ignored parameters (as the other answer already explained). While this may be considered acceptable, this habit may result in a conflict with `_` Underscore/Lodash namespace, also looks confusing when there are multiple ignored parameters. For this reason it is beneficial to have properly named underscored parameters (supported in TS 2.0), also saves time on figuring out function signature and why the parameters are marked as ignored (this defies the purpose of `_` parameter as a shortcut):

```
let fn = (param1, _unusedParam2, param3) => { ... };
```

For the reasons listed above, I would personally consider `_ => { ... }` code style a bad tone that should be avoided.

Comment: It's one character shorter but it is the same amount of keypresses for most IDEs, since pressing the `(` usually comes with a `)`. I personally prefer using  `p` for parameter, I also wonder if it has any performance issue

Comment: @Mojimi You likely have to either press `)` or the right-arrow-key to skip over that character however.

Answer (score 99):

> The `()` syntax conveys the intent better imho and is also more type specific

Not exactly. `()` says that the function does not expect any arguments, it doesn't declare any parameters. The function's `.length` is 0.

If you use `_`, it explicitly states that the function will be passed one argument, but that you don't care about it. The function's `.length` will be 1, which might matter in some frameworks.

So from a type perspective, it might be more accurate thing to do (especially when you don't type it with `any` but, say, `_: Event`). And as you said, it's one character less to type which is also easier to reach on some keyboards.

Comment: My first thought was that _ makes it only obvious by convention that there are no arguments to consider when trying to understand the function. Using () makes it explicit, no need for scanning the code for a possible use of _ (which would violate the convention). But you opened my eyes to also consider the value of documenting that there is a value passed to the function, which would otherwise not always be obvious.

Comment: I just realized my code is full of unused `_`s arrow function variables, I wonder if there's any performance difference compared to using `()`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your second paragraph. What about an underscore implies that you don't intend to use it? You certainly could, right?

Comment: @isherwood You could, yes, but then you should give it a proper name (even if something short like `e` for "event"). [The conventions is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27637013/1048572) [that `_` identifies an unused variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32197927/1048572).

Answer (score 29):

I guess `_ =>` is just used over `() =>` because `_` is common in other languages where it is not allowed to just omit parameters like in JS.

`_` is popular in Go and it's also used in Dart to indicate a parameter is ignored and probably others I don't know about.

Comment: Python also follows this convention, I think.

Comment: This usage of `_` was presumably borrowed from functional languages such as ML and Haskell, where it long predates the invention of Python (let alone Go, Dart, or TypeScript).

Comment: also Ruby does that (http://po-ru.com/diary/rubys-magic-underscore/)
and F# too (and other languages influenced by ML family)

Comment: Scala loves underscore (https://www.includehelp.com/scala/use-of-underscore-in-scala.aspx). Which more languages took after what Scala is doing with anonymous types with underscore.

Comment: I'd guess Scala also took it from some other language. There is hardly anything in programming languages that didn't exist already in the 70ties :D Mostly just new ways to combine the stuff.

Answer (score 15):

It is possisble to distinguish between the two usages, and some frameworks use this to represent different types of callbacks. For example I think nodes express framework uses this to distinguish between types of middleware, for example error handlers use three arguments, while routing uses two.

Such differentiation can look like the example below:

```js
const f1 = () => { } // A function taking no arguments
const f2 = _ => { }  // A function with one argument that doesn't use it

function h(ff) { 
  if (ff.length === 0) {
    console.log("No argument function - calling directly");
    ff();
  } else if (ff.length === 1) {
    console.log("Single argument function - calling with 1");
    ff(1);
  }
}

h(f1);
h(f2);
```

This is based off Bergi's answer, but I thought adding an example was a little more editing than I was happy to do to someone elses post.