# Negating the result of a promise in a guard

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular2-routing

I have a working angular2 guard with a `canActivate()` that calls a service for `isLoggedIn()` and returns a promise which then resolves and the route is handled appropiately.

However, I am trying to do the opposite, see when the user is not logged in, and it isn't working.

I tried something as simple as this (adding a ! operator), hoping it would work:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    canActivate() {
        return !this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

However, this always returns a falsey value and the route never activates.

This is a relevant excerpt of my `isLoggedIn()` function:

```
isLoggedIn(): Promise<Boolean> {
  var component = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {       
      component.queryForUser((user) => {
        resolve(user != null);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

If the user is not equal to `null`, then he is logged in and the promise resolves with true. Else, false.

While I could simply add a parameter to specify which state I am looking for, or even create a `isNotLoggedIn()` function,  with the same logic but inverted, I ask, Is there a way to negate the value of the promise's resolve for the `canActivate()`?

Comment: Treat a promise like a promise. `.then(...)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`return !this.authService.isLoggedIn()` won't work, because of how JS works. `this.authService.isLoggedIn()` is promise object and is truthy. `!this.authService.isLoggedIn()` will always be false.

Instead, promise result should be mapped to negated result with

```
canActivate() {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().then(result => !result);
}
```

Or

```
async canActivate() {
    return !(await this.authService.isLoggedIn());
}
```

The parentheses around `await ...` are optional and used for readability.

Comment: I'm new to TypeScript. So far I've used the `=>` operator in `(a) => (sth(a))` as a shorthand for `function(a) { sth(a) }`. What is `=>` doing in this case? Is it the same thing, just even shorter?

Comment: Strictly saying, it's `function(a) { return sth(a) }`, implicit return should always be kept in mind, because it can ruin things. Yes, it is a shorthand for one param. It's a matter of taste to use it or not. I personally don't use it in my own style guide because it is inconsistent (the inconsistency is discussed here in particular http://stackoverflow.com/a/41086381/3731501).

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is some further manipulation of the promise's resolved value:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().then(loggedIn => !loggedIn);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

And if you're inside an if statement and async/await is enabled move the negation inside the parenthesis.

```
if (!await client.bucketExists('test')) {}
```