# ESCMAScript 6 arrow functions - parentheses around parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm new to javascript and cannot understand simple thing - what is the difference between

```
(x) => { return x*2}
```

and

```
x => { return x*2} //(just for example, may not work)
```

Can someone explain or give link for description?

Comment: The parenthesis around `x` only are required when there are two or more input arguments. With just one (as you've shown here), the two statements are identical.

Comment: One has parens around a single argument, one doesn't; either is legal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions Note that using `...` here is potentially misleading depending on what they represent. They're a thing in ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085189/using-underscore-variable-with-arrow-functions-in-es6-typescript for some points on optional parentheses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parenthesis around input arguments (`x` in this case) are only required when there are two or more input arguments. With just one (as you've shown here), the two statements are identical.

`(x) => { return x * 2; }` is the same as `x => { return x * 2; }`

But,

`(x, y) => { return x * y; }`

Requires parenthesis around the input arguments.

See **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** for all the gory details!

Comment: Worth mentioning that you also need the parens if the first arg has a default, and/or uses destructuring.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes, but that is covered in the included link (part of the "gory" details).

Comment: Totally, I guess I was surprised by the absolute-ness of the statement `only required when there are two or more input arguments`, because that isn't true, there are other cases.

Comment: Also one useful part of the _gory details_ is that in simple cases where you only return a straightforward value, you can omit `return` keyword because it's implied. That is, `x => { return x * 2 }` is the same as `x => x * 2`

Comment: Another gory detail is how it works with ESlint and typescript: see [SO: expected parentheses around arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345240/expected-parentheses-around-arrow-function-argument-arrow-parens)