# Expected parentheses around arrow function argument. (arrow-parens)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

How to avoid Flow-type error on an `ES7` arrow function

```js
handleSelectCategory = (e) => {
  const { form } = this.state;

  let newCategories = [];
  if (form.categories.findIndex((c) => c.value === e.value) >= 0) {
    newCategories = form.categories.filter((c) => c.value !== e.value);
  } else {
    newCategories = [...form.categories, e];
  }
  this.setState({
    form: Object.assign({}, form, { categories: newCategories }),
  });
};
```

I receive the warning

```sh
Expected parentheses around arrow function argument. (arrow-parens)
```

Comment: It's not a type error, it's a linter warning. Have you considered [reading its documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens)?

Comment: same , but i looking for the configuration . my .eslintrc.js `'arrow-parens': ['error', 'as-needed'],` on vscode

Answer (score 15):

Parentheses around the parameter to an arrow function are optional in ES6 when there's only one argument, but ESLint complains about this by default. This is controlled by the [arrow-parens](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens) option.

Either change this option, or change your arrow functions to use `(c)` instead of `c` as the parameter lists.

Comment: 'arrow-parens' doesn't look to be part of eslint's ["recommended"](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) list. But it is part of the popular airbnb extension.

Comment: @SamVK I'm not a regular ESLint user, so I don't know what you mean by the recommended list. But the documentation I linked to says that "always" is the default setting.

Comment: `"always"` is the default option _if_ you include the rule in your eslint config's "rules" list (without specifically an option.) But by default, ESLint doesn't include the rule at all. (Technically, ESLint doesn't include _any_ rules by default, but running `eslint --init` [will add](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration) `"extends": "eslint:recommended"`, which adds all of eslint's "recommended" rules - but it's not on that list either.)

Comment: But actually I'm mistaken, it looks like [airbnb uses the "as-needed" option](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrows--one-arg-parens), so I'm not sure where the poster is even getting this rule added. They must be extending someone else's library that does include it, or added it themselves and forgot.

Comment: solve by `'arrow-parens': [true, 'ban-single-arg-parens', 'error', 'as-needed'],`