# Built-in way to use promises instead of adding event listener

Tags: javascript, promise, dom-events

I have some code using `addEventListener`. Just as an experiment, I wrote awrapper function to wrap arbitrary event listener calls with promises. There are probably better ways to do it. But is there a native API for either converting to promises or using promises instead of callbacks to handle events?  Obviously, this is a somewhat useless example, but does there exist a way to get a promise back natively when adding a new event handler?

```
function event(el, name) {
  return new Promise(resolve => el.addEventListener(name, e => resolve(e)));
}

let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
let audio = new Audio();

//Promise way
event(audio, 'ended').then(e => {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});

//Classic way
audio.addEventListener('ended', e => {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
audio.src = url;

audio.play();
```

Comment: You could try something like es6-promisify

Comment: I guess it doesn't exists, because events are made such that they can be triggered multiple times, whereas a promise ends only once. For example, if the event was a mouse click, the "Promise way" would trigger once whereas the "Classic way" would trigger on each click. I guess you have to code the promises yourself

Comment: No, there's not. Modern APIs do natively return promises, though.

Comment: @armagedescu [No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43877630/1048572)