# Why do fat arrow functions do not accept single parameter destruction without parentheses?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a question regarding fat arrow functions in JavaScript.

As the title says, fat arrow functions require the actual parentheses when destructing parameters even if only one parameter is being used and thus being destructed and I would like to know if this 'exception' exists on purpose or might it be implemented in ECMAScript in the future?

For example this works as expected:

```
let func = arg1 => {...}; // Single param
```

These however don't work as expected:

```
let func = => {...}; / let func => {...}; // No params
let func = arg1, arg2, ...restArg => {...}; // Multiple params
```

This way they do work:

```
let func = () => {...}; // No params
let func = (arg1, arg2, ...restArg) => {...}; // Multiple params
```

And now lets say we want to map through the entries of an object:

```
let obj = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
};

let objEntries = Object.entries(obj); // Array containing obj's entries
```

This works like it should:

```
objEntries.map(entry => {...}) // entry: ['x', 1], ['y', 2]
```

In this example I am trying to destruct the entry:

```
objEntries.map([key, value] => {...}) // Fails even though I am only using 1 param
objEntries.map(([key, value]) => {...}) // Succeeds like expected
```

So as I mentioned earlier I wonder why destructing inside the parentheses of a fat arrow function requires the actual parentheses even when only using and thus destructing only one parameter? Is that on purpose or might it be implemented in ECMAScript in the future?

Comment: The general syntax of fat arrow functions is `(params, ...) => { body }`. The shorthand is an exception to the rule and applies only and exclusively in the case of a plain single-parameter function. The reason for that is likely syntactical ambiguity and simplicity.

Comment: Pretty sure they designed a language that requires only a single lookahead in the token stream while parsing. If you have `let func = arg1, arg2, arg3 => ...`, then you don't actually know if it's a function until you look after the third parameter. But if there's a set of parens, they parse that, and they're back to a single lookahead to determine if it's a function.

Comment: Because destructured single param cannot be unambiguously parsed, and even if destructured array possibly can, the spec plays safe here. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086381/3731501 for a summary of param flavours.

Comment: @estus So, lets say destructed single parameter could be unambiguously parsed, would it be against the specification?

Comment: Yep. Because ES2015 didn't foresee it. This would require to include this in newer spec. Don't forget, there are destructured objects as well. They cannot be properly parsed without parentheses. It would be strange if destructured params were treated differently.

Comment: Even if the syntax is unambiguous in certain cases, the spec should not be more complex than necessary. Exempting plain single parameters benefits a huge percentage of use cases. Further exceptions would benefit very few use cases but make the rules incomprehensibly muddled. Javascript is a mass-market language, its syntax cannot be too complex without inevitably confusing thousands of people.