# What is the Underscore for in front of the arrow function (_=>) in the hero.service.ts Angular v5 Tour of Heroes Tutorial?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have either a typescript or javascript syntax issue.
Can someone tell me what _ => this.log... means?

I am used to seeing a name the parameter being passed into the arrow function there.

Does it simply mean 'no parameter'?

Ref: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-heroserviceupdatehero

```
    /** PUT: update the hero on the server */
updateHero (hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
  );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using \_ (underscore) variable with arrow functions in ES6/Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085189/using-underscore-variable-with-arrow-functions-in-es6-typescript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its nothing but a notion to name a parameter which isn't going to be used in the function.

Instead, they would have written it like this:

```
tap(() => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
```

If you want to read more, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085189/using-underscore-variable-with-arrow-functions-in-es6-typescript) is a good start.

Comment: I see now.    Any idea why we just could not write: 
 tap( this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`),

Comment: @OpTechMarketing Because `tap` expects a function to call, not a return value.

Answer (score 13):

`() => {console.log('Hello World')}`

`_ => {console.log('Hello World')}`

Both of the above are just the same if your function doesn't need a parameter.

The underscore `_` is just a throwaway variable, meaning it can be any variable name since it will never be used. It's just that they usually use the underscore to say that the function doesn't need a parameter.

I write my functions with no parameters using `()=>`, but I've seen a lot of versions using the underscore so it's good to understand both.