# TypeORM: Joining when we have one to many and many to one relationship

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

```ts
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({unique: true})
  username: string;

  @Column({unique: true})
  email: string;

  @OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.id)
  posts: Post[];
}

@Entity()
export class Post {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.posts)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'user_id'})
  user: User;

  @OneToMany(type => Image, image => image.id)
  images: Image[];
}
 
@Entity()
export class Image {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => Post, post => post.images)
  @JoinColumn({name : 'post_id'})
  post: Post;
}
```

I have these 3 entities and I want to make a query to have all the posts from a user and for that post to get all the images. I am trying to do this using the following code:

```ts
return await this.postRepository.createQueryBuilder("post")
  .innerJoinAndSelect("post.images", "image")
  .where("user_id = :userId", {userId: id})
  .getMany();
```

And I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined
```

I also tried this instead of the `.innerJoin` from above:

```
.innerJoinAndSelect(Image, "image", "image.post_id = post.id")
```

This way I don't get that error anymore, but as a result I get only the post and I don't get the images from it

Comment: How is it going? did you solve the probelm?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same problem myself.

You should change the relation here:

```js
@OneToMany(type => Image, image => image.id)
images: Image[];
```

To this:

```js
@OneToMany(type => Image, image => image.post)
images: Image[];
```

Notice that **`image.id`** should be **`image.post`** instead to match the inverse side.

*Edit =>
Over here the same problem appears:

```js
@OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.id)
posts: Post[];
```

This relation should also have the inverse side, **`post.id`** should be **`post.user`** instead:

```js
@OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user)
posts: Post[];
```

Be careful about this since it doesn't throw any errors until runtime.

I just tested this query with the above modifications and the error is gone:

```js
return await this.postRepository.find({
  relations: ['images', 'user'],
  where: { user: { id: id } },
});
```

You may also omit the **`@JoinColumn()`** decorators, as they are not necessary in *one to many* and *many to one* relationships, you can see it mentioned in the official docs:

> You can omit `@JoinColumn` in a `@ManyToOne` / `@OneToMany` relation. `@OneToMany` cannot exist without `@ManyToOne`. If you want to use `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` is required. Where you set `@ManyToOne` - its related entity will have "relation id" and foreign key.

Refer to the [TypeORM documentation](http://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) for more details about this, you will also find an example of this type of relation.

Comment: Using this method I get an error: 'type' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: You should be able to sort that out by replacing 'type' with either () or _
(Empty parentheses or underscore) to let the typescript compiler know you do not want to use it. You may find more info in this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086381/10952954

Comment: The problem with the TypeORM documentation is that it assumes you're using the sync feature, so the library _creates_ the join column so it knows which one is it. But it doesn't explain clearly how to deal with non-synced already existing tables.

Answer (score 22):

```
@Entity()
export class User {

 @OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user)
 posts: Post[];
}

@Entity()
export class Post {

 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number;

 @Column()
 user_id: number;

 @ManyToOne(type => User)
 @JoinColumn({name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'})
 user: User;

 @OneToMany(type => Image, image => image.post)
 images: Image[];
}

@Entity()
export class Image {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number;

 @Column()
 post_id: number;

 @ManyToOne(type => Post)
 @JoinColumn({name : 'post_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'})
 post: Post;
}
```

Try this

Comment: This worked. A column with the foreign key was to be added. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks ! I was missing the @JoinColumn decorator

Comment: Using this I get : "'type' is declared but its value is never read."

Comment: referencedColumnName: 'id' works for me!

Comment: If `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` are matched, no extra parameter is needed.
`@JoinColumn({name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'})`
`@JoinColumn()` // auto join