# 'Error' message: ''index' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

've setup eslint & eslint-plugin-react.

When I run ESLint, the linter returns no-unused-vars errors for each React component.

I'm assuming it's not recognizing that I'm using JSX or React syntax. Any ideas?
[image]

this my code--

Comment: Always paste real code, never images of code.

Answer (score 4):

In your codeblock

```
users.forEach((user, index) => { ... }) 
                     ^^^^^
```

you never use the parameter `index`, rendering it useless. That why ESLint complains - rightfully.

Instead go

```
users.forEach((user) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 2):

As another answer already explains, `no-unused-vars` rule triggers linter error because `index` parameter isn't in use. It can be omitted:

```
users.forEach(user => {
  /* ... */
});
```

If for some reason a parameter is temporarily not in use but is expected to be used later, or it's needed for proper function arity (this is not the case for `forEach`), it can be marked as unused (conventionally, [underscored parameters treated as such](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern)):

```
users.forEach((user, _index) => {
  /* ... */
});
```

`Expected parentheses around arrow function argument` linter error means that it was configured to enforce optional parentheses in arrow functions with [`arrow-parens` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens). This can be changed by either disabling this rule or adding parentheses:

```
users.forEach((user) => {
  /* ... */
});
```

The latter option may be preferred because enforced arrow parentheses [are more consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086381/3731501).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing to the underscored parameter convention

Answer (score 0):

```
 handleSelectAll = () => {
    const { users } = this.props.users
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState }
      newState.selects = []
      users.forEach(user => {
        newState.selects.push(!prevState.selectedAll)
      });
      newState.selectedAll = !prevState.selectedAll
      return newState
    })
  }
```

"message: 'Expected parentheses around arrow function argument. (arrow-parens)"

Comment: Check my updated answer. The error messages from ESLint are clearly understandable, what's your issue? Btw, ESLint cannot help with unwillingness to look it up.

Comment: What does the post means? Did you come across 'Expected parentheses around arrow function argument'?