# Function without argument : () or _

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I got question for you.

When you create a function without argument you used to do

```
const function myFunction = () => {
...
}
```

but recently i found we could do the same thing with `_`

```
const function myFunction = _ => {
...
}
```

so, my question is, what's the difference?

Is it being wrong to use `_` just 'cause everyone use `()` ?

Comment: The defined functions are not the same. The first `myFunction` has no arguments (`myFunction.length === 0`), the second one has one argument (`myFunction.length === 1`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085189/using-underscore-variable-with-arrow-functions-in-es6-typescript

Comment: @Andreas is correct. However, this almost never matters. The second pattern is sometimes called "a discard" or "discard parameter" where you *take* a parameter but never intend to use it. `_` is somewhat of a convention to signify that, e.g.  `(_, foo) => { /* ... */ }` is a function that takes two parameters but *discards* the first one and doesn't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` is a list of zero parameters.

`(_)` is a list of one parameter (named `_`)

`_` is a shorthand for `(_)` because the parentheses are optional when there is exactly one parameter.

---

"Wrong" is subjective, but:

- if a function doesn't use any parameters then providing a variable to assign them to doesn't make sense (not even if it has a name which tells you nothing about what it is for).
- writing non-idiomatic code imposes barriers for people who have to come along and maintain your code later.

---

Aside: You have a syntax error. You can't combine the `function` keyword with an arrow function.

Comment: "*writing non-idiomatic code imposes barriers for people who have to come along and maintain your code later.*" but `_` is quite widely used to mean "I declare this parameter but don't intend to use it". In C# it's an actual language feature, so you can discard multiple `(_, _, third) => third + 1` whereas this is a syntax error in JS. Still, `Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => i + 1)` is a common enough example of a discard used in JS.

Comment: @VLAZ — Generally only when the function is being written to conform to a callback specification and later paramters are needed, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a function its possible to specify only one parameter without parantheses.

```
const myFunction = _ => _ * 2
```

returns 4 when you call the function like

```
myFunction(2)
```